# Hosting a website with SQL Server Express on personal machine

Tags: sql-server, self-hosting

I have a small community thing with some friends for which I have made a website. We have a machine we rent for hosting game servers, on this machine I'd like to also try and host the SQL Database Server thingie but Im just stuck.

I've currently installed SQL Server Express and from that Im lost, cant find anything on how to set it up as if it was a proper database webhost.

Currently quite new to making websites but I do have a fullstack .net education.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to use SQL Server? I think you are missing a piece of the puzzle  that exposes the data from the SQL Server and presents it on a website (MVC, webapi, etc.).

Comment: I'm probably missing some bits yeah. Never tried this before.
Im using APS .NET with MVC for the website.
But my issue is I dont know how to set up the SQL Server on the server machine

Comment: Probably botched the question completely.
What Im trying to figure out is how to set up a personal web host with SQL Database on a machine.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't expose websites, you will have to add another layer (for example Apache Tomcat, IIS, Nginx, etc.) that involves another programming languages (like C#, java, PHP together with HTML, javascript and CSS) that exposes your website or web services and connects to your SQL Server to retrieve and manipulate data. Tons of frameworks and tutorals you can search online. Good luck!

Comment: I think I have that in my project via autofactory? Im not sure.
Also seems like it's mostly me not being able to explain what Im trying to do.
Say I have this server machine with SQL Server on, I have my personal computer with the website that needs the connection string to the database. 
How would I go on to get that connection string setup on the server?
And thank you for helping

Comment: A basic connection string just requires the SQL Server login's username and password (or via windows integrated security), and the IP of the machine. The format of the connection string might vary slightly depending on the framework you use to connect to the database. `Server=IPHost\mySQLServerInstanceName; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; 
Password=myPassword;`

Comment: How would I then go on about getting the SQL Server login? Looking at the apps that came with the install I cant seem to find any login info??
Never used Windows Integrated Security, do I have to use that on my server with the SQL Server? and if so then how?

On a side note it feels like I took a bit too big a bite by trying to do this.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to manage your SQL Server instance, then you will have a default `sa` administrator login listed under Security -> Logins. Try to follow a basic SQL Server administration tutorial and post back (in another question) any problem you might get.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you for the help